# values sent with POST/GET will not print as variables

Tags: php, html, post, get

I am working on a project to take two submitted variables and turn them into php variables (eventually they will multiply together) but as of now I cannot get the variables to be treated as such/echo.

I tried changing from POST to GET and the variables are sent through (appear in query line) but they don't print on the page

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo $_POST['length'];

        echo $_POST['numPass'];
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="number" name="length">
    <input type="number" name="numPass">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I expect that the variables will be echoed as a regular statement. 
ie. length=2 and numPass=4

```
24
```

Comment: Try `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>\n";` to test your input.

Comment: please use `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET` instead of post

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `$_GET` and `$_POST` request using `$_REQUEST`

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    echo $_REQUEST['length'];

    echo $_REQUEST['numPass'];
}

<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="number" name="length">
  <input type="number" name="numPass">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

$POST['submit'] does not exist because your submit button does not have a name, it needs a name the same as your other inputs

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check the input to avoid possible errors. You can try its example:

```
<?php
if( $_POST["length"] && $_POST["numPass"] ) { 
    echo "1: " . $_POST['length'] . "<br>";
    echo "2: " . $_POST['numPass'] . "<br>";
    echo $_POST['length'] * $_POST['numPass'];
}
?>

<form method="post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <input type="number" name="length">
    <input type="number" name="numPass">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```